# Workflow send Email SharePoint 2013 Host Web

Tags: workflow

I have a Calander list in the host web how could i create a workflow that based on when item is added to list, send email to that user.

Regards, Martin

Answer (score 1):

You can try making the workflow in SPD that triggers on item created to the list.
Then in the WF you add the Send email action and log it to see if it is done.
[image]